# woocommerce customize checkout order reviews

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I've done some changes in the woocommerce `.php files` to display the checkout the way it needs to be for my case but by doing so, I've learned that it will be or maybe be erased with the next update. I don't have the abilities and don't know what to write in the `functions.php` file to apply theses changes permanently and don't know if it's possible to do it.

here is what I achieved to do, and there are a few things that need to be added.

- add (exclu. tax) to `product-price`
- show `product-subtotal` tax included and not excluded
- add (exclu.tax) to the `fee-total`

[image]

As you can maybe see fees are showing after the `cart-subtotal`

Is there someone that could think about what I need to write in `functions.php` to make this happens and is that possible without touching the `.php files` of woocommerce ?

thank you !

Comment: WooCommerce already has that kind of thing, if you properly configure your tax settings.

Comment: If you haven't check TAX documentation, please check it here https://woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/

Comment: You need to create a child theme https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/